# Unable to Verify Contract Code. Help!

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

The method of creating the contract was little unorthodox in a way that it was a flattened code from the start to deploy. Verified with Remix that everything works perfectly. The code was done on atom IDE and launched from ethereum wallet. SRCICO takes one argument which is an a wallet address. Can someone tell me where the mistake is?

Here is the error I get

> Note: Contract was created during Txn#
>   [0x30f829e20f0a28c2a5564e3806aaff7591292ab38d67fe671f309b326deef17b] 
>   Result: Does not match the input creation bytecode found at this
>   address
>
> Sorry! The Compiled Contract ByteCode for 'SRCICO' does NOT match the
>   Contract Creation Code for
>   [0xef8cf79c21637fc6f951bcac348915508a639a41].
>
> Contract name(s) found: 'BasicToken' , 'ERC20' , 'ERC20Basic' ,
>   'Ownable' , 'Pausable' , 'PausableToken' , 'SRCICO' , 'SRCToken' ,
>   'SafeERC20' , 'SafeMath' , 'StandardToken'  Unable to Verify Contract
>   source code.

Here is the code

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.18;



  contract Ownable {
    address public owner;


    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    function Ownable() public {
      owner = msg.sender;
    }


    modifier onlyOwner() {
      require(msg.sender == owner);
      _;
    }


    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
      require(newOwner != address(0));
      OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
      owner = newOwner;
    }

  }

  contract Pausable is Ownable {
    event Pause();
    event Unpause();

    bool public paused = false;


    modifier whenNotPaused() {
      require(!paused);
      _;
    }

    modifier whenPaused() {
      require(paused);
      _;
    }


    function pause() onlyOwner whenNotPaused public {
      paused = true;
      Pause();
    }

    function unpause() onlyOwner whenPaused public {
      paused = false;
      Unpause();
    }
  }

  contract SRCICO is Pausable{
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint constant public minContribAmount = 0.01 ether;

    SRCToken public token;
    uint256 constant public tokenDecimals = 18;


    uint256 public startTime;
    uint256 public endTime;

    bool public icoEnabled;

    address public multisignWallet;

    uint256 public weiRaised;

    uint256 constant public totalSupply = 15000000 * (10 ** tokenDecimals);
    uint256 constant public preSaleCap = 1000 * (10 ** tokenDecimals);
    uint256 constant public initialICOCap = 1000 * (10 ** tokenDecimals);
    uint256 constant public tokensForTeam = 4500000 * (10 ** tokenDecimals);


    uint256 public soldPreSaleTokens;
    uint256 public sentPreSaleTokens;

    uint256 public icoCap;
    uint256 public icoSoldTokens;
    bool public icoEnded = false;


    uint256 constant public RATE_FOR_WEEK1 = 800000;
    uint256 constant public RATE_FOR_WEEK2 = 750000;
    uint256 constant public RATE_NO_DISCOUNT = 700000;

    event TokenPurchase(address indexed purchaser, address indexed beneficiary, uint256 value, uint256 amount);


    function SRCICO(address _multisignWallet) public {
      require(_multisignWallet != address(0));
      token = createTokenContract();
      uint256 tokensToDao = tokensForTeam;
      multisignWallet = _multisignWallet;
      token.transfer(multisignWallet, tokensToDao);
    }


    function createTokenContract() internal returns (SRCToken) {
      return new SRCToken();
    }


    function enableTokenTransferability() external onlyOwner {
      require(token != address(0));
      token.unpause();
    }

    function disableTokenTransferability() external onlyOwner {
      require(token != address(0));
      token.pause();
    }


    function setSoldPreSaleTokens(uint256 _soldPreSaleTokens) external onlyOwner{
      require(!icoEnabled);
      require(_soldPreSaleTokens <= preSaleCap);
      soldPreSaleTokens = _soldPreSaleTokens;
    }


    function setMultisignWallet(address _multisignWallet) external onlyOwner{
      require(!icoEnabled || now < startTime);
      require(_multisignWallet != address(0));
      multisignWallet = _multisignWallet;
    }


    function setContributionDates(uint64 _startTime, uint64 _endTime) external onlyOwner{
      require(!icoEnabled);
      require(_startTime >= now);
      require(_endTime >= _startTime);
      startTime = _startTime;
      endTime = _endTime;
    }



    function enableICO() external onlyOwner{

      icoEnabled = true;
      icoCap = initialICOCap.add(preSaleCap).sub(soldPreSaleTokens);
    }


    function () payable whenNotPaused public {
      purchaseTokens(msg.sender);
    }

    // low level token purchase function
    function purchaseTokens(address beneficiary) public payable whenNotPaused {
      require(beneficiary != address(0));
      require(validPurchase());

      uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;
      uint256 returnWeiAmount;

      uint rate = getRate();
      assert(rate > 0);
      uint256 tokens = weiAmount.mul(rate);

      uint256 newIcoSoldTokens = icoSoldTokens.add(tokens);

      if (newIcoSoldTokens > icoCap) {
          newIcoSoldTokens = icoCap;
          tokens = icoCap.sub(icoSoldTokens);
          uint256 newWeiAmount = tokens.div(rate);
          returnWeiAmount = weiAmount.sub(newWeiAmount);
          weiAmount = newWeiAmount;
      }

      // update state
      weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

      token.transfer(beneficiary, tokens);
      icoSoldTokens = newIcoSoldTokens;
      if (returnWeiAmount > 0){
          msg.sender.transfer(returnWeiAmount);
      }

      TokenPurchase(msg.sender, beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);

      sendFunds();
    }

    function sendFunds() internal {
      multisignWallet.transfer(this.balance);
    }


    function validPurchase() internal constant returns (bool) {
      bool withinPeriod = now >= startTime && now <= endTime;
      bool nonMinimumPurchase = msg.value >= minContribAmount;
      bool icoTokensAvailable = icoSoldTokens < icoCap;
      return !icoEnded && icoEnabled && withinPeriod && nonMinimumPurchase && icoTokensAvailable;
    }

    function endIco() external onlyOwner {
      require(!icoEnded);
      icoEnded = true;

      uint256 unsoldTokens = icoCap.sub(icoSoldTokens);
      token.transfer(multisignWallet, unsoldTokens);
    }


    function hasEnded() public constant returns (bool) {
      return (icoEnded || icoSoldTokens >= icoCap || now > endTime);
    }


    function getRate() public constant returns(uint){
      require(now >= startTime);
      if (now < startTime.add(4 weeks)){
        // January
        return RATE_FOR_WEEK1;
      }else if (now < startTime.add(8 weeks)){
        // week 2
        return RATE_FOR_WEEK2;
      }else if (now < endTime){
        // no discount
        return RATE_NO_DISCOUNT;
      }
      return 0;
    }

    function drain() external onlyOwner {
      owner.transfer(this.balance);
    }
  }

  contract ERC20Basic {
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    function balanceOf(address who) public constant returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
  }

  contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
      require(_to != address(0));
      require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

      // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
      balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
      balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
      Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
      return true;
    }


    function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint256 balance) {
      return balances[_owner];
    }

  }

  contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public constant returns (uint256);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
  }

  library SafeERC20 {
    function safeTransfer(ERC20Basic token, address to, uint256 value) internal {
      assert(token.transfer(to, value));
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(ERC20 token, address from, address to, uint256 value) internal {
      assert(token.transferFrom(from, to, value));
    }

    function safeApprove(ERC20 token, address spender, uint256 value) internal {
      assert(token.approve(spender, value));
    }
  }


  contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;


    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
      require(_to != address(0));
      require(_value <= balances[_from]);
      require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

      balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
      balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
      allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
      Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
      return true;
    }


    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
      Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
      return true;
    }


    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
      return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }


    function increaseApproval (address _spender, uint _addedValue) public returns (bool success) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);
      Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
      return true;
    }

    function decreaseApproval (address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public returns (bool success) {
      uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
      if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
      } else {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
      }
      Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
      return true;
    }

  }

  contract PausableToken is StandardToken, Pausable {
    modifier whenNotPausedOrOwner() {
      require(msg.sender == owner || !paused);
      _;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public whenNotPausedOrOwner returns (bool) {
      return super.transfer(_to, _value);
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public whenNotPausedOrOwner returns (bool) {
      return super.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public whenNotPausedOrOwner returns (bool) {
      return super.approve(_spender, _value);
    }

    function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public whenNotPausedOrOwner returns (bool success) {
      return super.increaseApproval(_spender, _addedValue);
    }

    function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public whenNotPausedOrOwner returns (bool success) {
      return super.decreaseApproval(_spender, _subtractedValue);
    }
  }

  contract SRCToken is PausableToken {
    string constant public name = "SRCOIN";
    string constant public symbol = "SRCOIN";
    uint256 constant public decimals = 18;
    uint256 constant TOKEN_UNIT = 10 ** uint256(decimals);
    uint256 constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10500000 * TOKEN_UNIT;

    function SRCToken() public {
      // Set untransferable by default to the token
      paused = true;
      // asign all tokens to the contract creator
      totalSupply = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
      Transfer(0x0, msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
      balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    }
  }

  library SafeMath {
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      uint256 c = a * b;
      assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
      return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      uint256 c = a / b;
      return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      assert(b <= a);
      return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      uint256 c = a + b;
      assert(c >= a);
      return c;
    }
  }
```

Constructor Argument ABI

```
0000000000000000000000003671bd107790b6de24bec933bd24cca7b47cc75e
```

Comment: Are you sure the compiler options are the same (version, optimization enable, etc)?

Comment: Just tried to validate using your data.
I get a message - 
ByteCode (what we are looking for): **(empty)**
== has no byte code.
I would consult etherscan group. its a few guys doing this project. 
Also noticed the suggested ctor arguments are wrong. till now for all contracts I validated. the ctor arguments suggested by etherscan were correct.